# $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {(-2)^n \over n} $ How does this converge or diverge using the alternate series test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {(-2)^n \over n} $$

When I took the limit I got -2, I also tried using ratio and root test and got the same answer. The answer is supposed to be divergent I think but I thought if Rho<1 it is convergent, unless you can't have negative limits?

Comment: How quickly does the numerator grow (in absolute terms) as compared to the denominator? No need for these test. As a sequence, it diverges...

Comment: @imranfat Much larger

Comment: If the sequence diverges, as you understand, so does the  series. That is where it basically ends

Comment: @imranfat That I understand, I'm just not sure how I'd prove it

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$. This is because $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ converges to $s$ implies that $a_{n+1}=s_{n+1}-s_n$ converges to $s-s=0$. Therefore if $a_n\not\to0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not converge - the contrapositive implication.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that alternate series test says that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$
converges if $a_n$ is an eventually decreasing sequence to $0$. In your case, $a_n = \dfrac{2^n}n$. This is increasing and diverges. Hence, alternate series test is not applicable in this case.

You can directly conclude that the series doesn't converge, since a necessary condition for a series to converge is that the $n^{th}$ term converges to zero. In your case, the $n^{th}$ terms doesn't converge at all in the first place.

Comment: Right, so because it's -2, which isn't equal to 0, then it diverges. Thanks, I can't keep track of all these rules

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test states that if
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| =r $$
And $r \gt 1$, then the series diverges. So now we have
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\frac{(-2)^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(-2)^n}{n}}\right| = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-2)^{n+1}n}{(-2)^n(n+1)}\right| $$
$$= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-2)^{n}(-2)n}{(-2)^n(n+1)}\right| = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{-2n}{n+1}\right| $$
$$= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{2n}{n+1}\right| = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{1+\frac1n} =2$$
Therefore by the ratio test,
$$ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^n}{n}\Rightarrow \mbox{diverges} $$

Comment: I'd love to know what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: The nth term test is usually easier when it is applicable, but this is still technically correct, so I upvoted.

Comment: @Ian, agreed. I only used the ratio test to show the OP that $r$ is in fact greater than $1$.